# Maven tests troubles with SOAP having Java EE 6 dependency

Tags: maven, soap, java-ee-6

I'm finding troubles when trying to use SOAP in tests in a maven project that has Java EE 6 API as a provided-scoped dependency.

**Important facts**

1. I'm aware that [the API is unusable for testing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/unittesting-455385.html)
2. I know I should import an implementation of any specification if I want to use it
3. [SOAP is part of Java SE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/soap/package-summary.html), not EE
4. SOAP (mock) classes are included in [the Maven artifact](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cjavax%7Cjavaee-api%7C6.0%7Cjar) and I believe they should not
5. This happens in Java EE 6, but [those classes have been removed in version 7](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cjavax%7Cjavaee-api%7C7.0%7Cjar)
6. If I remove the dependency, the tests work fine
7. When using 7.0 version of the API everything works

**Exception**

```
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/xml/messaging/URLEndpoint
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:455)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:367)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.call(HttpSOAPConnection.java:102)
        at somecompany.someproject.service.SomeBean.someMethod(SomeBean.java:##)
        at somecompany.someproject.service.SomeBeanTest.testSomeMethod(SomeBeanTest.java:##)
```

**POM configuration**

```
<dependencies>
  ...
  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  ...
</dependencies>

<build>
  ...
  <plugins>
    ...
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.17</version>
      ...
    </plugin>
    ...
  </plugins>
  ...
</build>
```

**Failed solutions**

I have tried several solutions (not going to post each one for clarity, but will post them by request):

1. I have tried every single `<scope/>` in Maven and none disables the library in tests
2. Also, tried excluding the library as a dependency of the plugin
3. Including rj.jar as a system dependency with a higher priority than javaee-api one didn't work either

**Unwanted workaround**

I got the tests working using 7.0 dependency but this is unacceptable according to policies, so I need to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got to make it work using the property `classpathDependencyExcludes` of the `maven-surefire-plugin`:

```
<build>
  ...
  <plugins>
    ...
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.17</version>
      ...
      <configuration>
        <classpathDependencyExcludes>
          <classpathDependencyExcludes>javax:javaee-api</classpathDependencyExcludes>
        </classpathDependencyExcludes>
        ...
      </configuration>
      ...
    </plugin>
    ...
  </plugins>
  ...
</build>
```

I'm going to leave this posted as I believe I'll not be the only one experiencing this at some point.

Comment: It's curious how I found my own solution in 10 minutes after several hours struggling for a solution, probably just because writting down the question and making my head put everything in its place.

Answer (score 0):

I was running in the same problem as below while running java class.
Exception:
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/xml/messaging/URLEndpoint

With Java8 as runtime, I finally included correct version (7.0) and the program started working fine earlier it was taking version 6.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>7.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```