# Generic WS client for Weblogic

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am running an application on Jboss 7 and Weblogic 12 , when I make a soap call on weblogic is more restrictive than jboss. My client interface has to implements all the methods of the wsdl and the annotation for the method and parameters and return type have to be exactly the same. Jboss is more permissive.
Is there a way to implement a simple generic client for a soap call without have to implements all the methods of the wsdl running on Weblogic? Just with the method i need?

In my specific case I'm implementing a simple client to make a call to only a method of the ws (where the return type is void cos I don't need/want to implement the structure of the returning object and my interface is not implementing all methods of the wsdl), under weblogic I'm getting the following error:

> com.sun.xml.ws.api.wsdl.parser.WSDLParserExtensionContext.getWSDLModel()Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/model/wsdl/editable/EditableWSDLModel;
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   com.sun.xml.ws.api.wsdl.parser.WSDLParserExtensionContext.getWSDLModel()Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/model/wsdl/editable/EditableWSDLModel;
>           at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.framework.policy.WSDLParserExtension.definitionsElements(WSDLParserExtension.java:541)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved using SAAJ

I followed this example http://www.concretepage.com/webservices/java-saaj-web-service-example

But in my pom I had to change javaee-api version from 6.0 to 7.0

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>7.0</version>
 </dependency>
```

I tried to follow this suggestion

[Maven tests troubles with SOAP having Java EE 6 dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26055085/maven-tests-troubles-with-soap-having-java-ee-6-dependency)

but the solution doesn't work for me